# OData substringof or startswith returning all items

Tags: rest, jquery, odata, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to filter my results from a Rest Call.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Title,Id&$startswith('Title','" + request.term + "') eq true",
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (ex) {
    }
});
```

In my Contacts List i'm trying to retrieve the Title and the Id for Items which start with a String or which have the String somewhere in it, here for example it is the Name of somebody.

I also tried it with substringof:

```
"/_api/lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Title,Id&$substringof(" + request.term + ",'Title') eq true"
```

which delivers also the same result.

It gives me all List Items from the List and no Filtering is applied.
I build the Url for the Rest after looking here [Programming using the SharePoint 2013 REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385.aspx#bk_determining)
Like the Schema given there I think the Url looks ok, but it not seems so :)

**Edit:**

Applying the `$filter` like in the OData Uri Conventions gives me the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The query is not valid."}}}
```

Tried it with following Query Strings:

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Title,Id&$filter=substringof(m,'Title') eq true

_api/lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Title,Id&$filter=substringof('m','Title') eq true

_api/lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Title,Id&$filter=substringof('m',Title) eq true
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've managed to get the filter with substringof returning the correct results when I removed the "eq true".

Using one of your query strings, it should work like this:

```
_api/lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items?$select=Title,Id&$filter=substringof('m',Title)
```

I haven't checked any other functions, but at least, the same happens with startswith function.

Answer (score 10):

For anyone looking at this question, I can report that

```
/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Applications')/items?$filter=startswith(Title,'1AAJ')
```

IS working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/uri-conventions/ for the correct uri convention.

Should be

```
/_api/lists/getByTitle('Contacts')     
/items?$select=Title,Id&$filter=substringof(" + request.term + ",'Title') eq true"
```

So with the $filter included

Comment: please see my edit. When I apply the $filter it gives me an error that the query is not in a correct format

Comment: Maybe it is because of the combination/order of the $select, it seems it should work. http://sharepoint.mindsharpblogs.com/NancyB/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=b6efd474-248a-4b16-ab88-afdb6fa31b65&ID=25.
Could you try with just the filter?

Comment: Tried it with only the filter the same Error is returning. Theres probably something missing but I don't get it. When i'm looking at the conventions it looks ok

Answer (score 0):

I tried your query URI on my endpoint and applied some changes:
- The second parameter of the substring shouldn't be a string, so I removed the apostropes

After this I get the results:

http://jaydata.org/examples/Northwind.svc/Products?$select=Product_ID,Product_Name&$filter=substringof('CH',Product_Name)

My endpoint is standard WCF Data Service, and the filter is working.

If changing the URI still returns all records, that would be a SherePoint trick I guess. What happens if you put 'zzz' or some random string in the filter?

Comment: Tested it also again with that string, but it is only returning the same error "The query is not valid." when i'm using the $filter tag

Answer (score -1):

Also, the contains method works and I've had better compatibility with it.  The syntax is:

```
api/People?$filter=contains(LastName,%27Smith%27)&$select=LastName,FirstName
```

Comment: The contains parameter definitely works, as referenced at http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/.  It's one of the easier filter partial matches.  I don't have Sharepoint 2013, so I can't test against it, but it work for anyone using a modern and standard implementation of OData.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I thought the topic was related to SP 2013. Please can you edit you answer so I can remove my downvote? thanks