# SharePoint 2013 REST Query By ContentTypeId

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I am trying to get all the folders items inside of a list. I know that folder content types start with 0x0120. So I wrote these two queries

```
 http://sharepoint.com/sites/dev3/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Discussions')/items?$filter=substringof(%270x0120%27,ContentTypeId)
```

This returns no results.

(this was a solution recommended in this thread [OData substringof or startswith returning all items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100697/odata-substringof-or-startswith-returning-all-items))

I also tried

```
http://sharepoint.com/sites/dev3/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Discussions')/items?$startswith(%270x0120%27,ContentTypeId)
```

This returns results but it returns everything ... it does not really do the filtering based on the ID specified by me.

i also tried

```
http://sharepoint.com/sites/dev3/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/dev3/lists/Discussions')/folders
```

This gives results... but does not return details like the Item Id which I need.

My end object is that if there is a list which has a folder called Foo and an Item called Bar. the query should fetch only the Foo folder and give me details like the   etc.

I am looking for a REST solution (no CAML). so far the soltuions which I have tried either return everything Foo and Bar. or nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer. putting it here so that it helps someone

web/lists/getbytitle('List)/items?$filter=startswith(ContentTypeId,'0x0120')

Comment: I'm having the same issues. And I tried the endpoint above and it's still returning empty. What can be the issue?